# Rotating a Label In Qt with Python

Tags: python, qt

I'm somewhat new to Qt and was wondering how to rotate a Label that has a pixmap inside of it. I've tried somethings like this:

```
    def paintEvent (self, event):
        t = QtGui.QTransform()
        image = QtGui.QImage(_fromUtf8(":/icons/BOOM_OUT.png"))
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        t.translate(400,300)
        t.rotate(45)

        p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        p.setTransform(t)
        p.drawPixmap((-pixmap.width()/2),(-pixmap.height()/2), pixmap)
        p.end()
```

I know that the drawPixmap doesn't reference the label, but I cannot get this to work. 
I feel like this should be easy, but from everything I have read it seems somewhat difficult. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the eventuality that it is not intended, note that translate and rotate is not the same as rotate and translate. For the vast majority of transformations of UI controls I have worked with, rotation is best suited before the translation. However this is up to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I fixed this in my code and will make sure to do this in the future, but I still don't know how to apply the transformations to my label

Comment: Use `QPixmap::transformed` to transform the pixmap once before adding it to label. Manipulating with pixmaps in `paintEvent` is highly inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but rotating the image / pixmap and leaving the label's `paintEvent` unchanged seems easier:

```
 # load your image
image = QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/icons/BOOM_OUT.png"))

# prepare transform
t = QtGui.QTransform()
t.rotate(45)

# rotate the pixmap
rotated_pixmap = pixmap.transformed(t)

# and let the label show the rotated version
label.setPixmap(rotated_pixmap)
```

Comment: You don't have to use `QImage` here. This can (and should) be done entirely with `QPixmap`.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov You're right - I overlooked that `QPixmap` has all the necessary stuff as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! This does work and I could use it but it would take a lot of work around. Is there anyway to rotate the label itself so that the label's coordinates change?

Comment: Consider using `QGraphicsView` if you want better transformations and coordinates transitions support.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Do you know of any good resources to learn QGraphicsView with python? I've had trouble finding some reliable ones

Comment: There is almost nothing python-specific in this topic. You can read [this overview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) for C++. Transforming C++ code to python is quite easy.